# Preventing iOS Automation Instruments from automatically retrying the test after failure

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

When my test runs into a critical failure such as tapping an invalid element the Automation Instrument attempts to restart the test from the beginning which results in a lot of errors and can even lag my system, making it difficult to stop the test. I don't have the repeat option enabled. Is there a way of preventing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon what you can do is: try capturing when your test runs into a failure by means of a try/catch block.

When your test fails, it will jump inside the catch block and you can stop it there.

Maybe something like this.

```
try {
  // Run your tests
} catch (exception){
  UIALogger.logFail("Test failed with error message: " + exception.message);
}
```

I think that the logFail() method should be enough to keep your tests from running indefinately.

Comment: I tried that unfortunately. It seems like if I throw an error that I don't catch myself the system keeps trying, as if its errors are different than the standard JavaScript errors.

Comment: Actually coming back to this, if I wrap EVERYTHING inside of a try catch like you suggested then the test won't try to automatically restart. I don't quite understand why this is the case but for now it'll work.